# Isuzu NPR Mechanic -

Tags: electrical, isuzu

My 2004 NPR w4500 truck has an electrical problem of shutting off approx 60-90 seconds after turning on and running.  It restarts perfectly.  But does this forever.  I have a engine protection system added onto it that indicates its an batter problem.  I was told by some to remove this device because of the long term success of it. Just replaced both batteries.  No success.  Truck is not able to function and thus screwed up my landscape business.  Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think, if for no other reason than curiosity, I'd try disconnecting the engine protection system ... if it will let you do it. If you just changed out the batteries and it's still giving you the same code, it seems it's not reading "something" correctly. It could at least be worth a try.

Comment: Some things related to battery issues to consider; battery cables, their connections and corrosion, drive belt and alternator.